# How to sort matching colums

Tags: database, sorting, google-sheets, multiple-columns, columnsorting

I have a huge database to sort. Basically I have datas from 2 periods. Over the years let's say people joined the database while others leaved.

Here is a screenshot :

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAf21.png)

How can I come to this type of result where everything is sorted :

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nygT.png)

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "everything is sorted"? Alphabetical by particular column? Grouped by repeated entries in particular column? What happens to spaces? etc.

Comment: Well I need similar names to match the same lines (ex:456,457)
For spaces I don't really know. For example if PIERRE has a new quality over the years, a blank square need to be there

Comment: "Similar" names? Please define your input data and your desired output in the question. Consult guide on [minimal, viable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as needed. Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you can see the pictures I linked, but names (in this case JULIE, PIERRE etc.) need to be on the same lines. So it can't really be an alphabetical sort cause if someone join the database it won't work I guess

Comment: Yes, I read your question, including the two linked images and found your question unclear.

Comment: I know it's complicated to explain what I want, but can't we sort while matching words in columns ? And also of course create blank squares if needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to solve this problem you should use google-script.

This is an option using pure google-sheet formula, hopefully can help you somewhat

**Method 1:**

```
=ArrayFormula({INDEX(SPLIT(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1),INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1)<>""),"/"),0,1),
IF(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,2),INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1)<>"")<>"",INDEX(SPLIT(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1),INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1)<>""),"/"),0,2),),
IF(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,3),INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1)<>"")<>"",INDEX(SPLIT(FILTER(INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1),INDEX(QUERY({SPLIT("2005"&"#"&FILTER(A2:A&"/"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"#");SPLIT("2015"&"#"&FILTER(C2:C&"/"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"#")},"select Col2,count(Col2) group by Col2 pivot Col1"),0,1)<>""),"/"),0,2),)})
```

[image]

---

**Method 2:** **(make formula more compact)**

```
=QUERY(ArrayFormula({SPLIT("2005"&"|"&FILTER(A2:A&"|"&B2:B,A2:A<>""),"|");
                     SPLIT("2015"&"|"&FILTER(C2:C&"|"&D2:D,C2:C<>""),"|")}),
       "select Col2,min(Col3) group by Col2,Col3 pivot Col1 order by Col2")
```

[image]

Comment: Well thank you very much I'll try this for sure